# Reading a JSON formatted file in php

Tags: php, json

I'm very new at JSON, I'm trying to read one parameter of this file using php:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => OK
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [types] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => route
                        )

                    [formatted_address] => Foro Umberto I, 90133 Palermo, Italy
                    [address_components] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [long_name] => Foro Umberto I
                                    [short_name] => SS113
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => route
                                        )

                                )
```

This is only a part, anyway, i need to echo the `formatted_address` using php, but i can get it, this is part of my code:

```
$address = json_decode($curlData);
echo($address -> {'formatted_address'});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$data = json_decode($curlData);
$result = $data->results[0];
$address = $result->formatted_address;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the brackets or the quotes:

```
echo $address -> formatted_address;
```

Also, for what it's worth, when you use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) you can also have it return an array instead of an object by telling it `true` in the second argument:

```
$address = json_decode($whatever, true);
echo $address['formatted_address'];
```

...If that helps you any.

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$formatted_address in C:\WAMP2\www\ReverseGeo\index.php on line 17

Comment: @DomingoSL I missed the `Array` part in there. Have you tried Rocket's solution?

Answer (score 0):

After decoding the json you just have a plain old PHP object, so you can do this:

```
$address->formatted_address
```